# nvidia graphics card showing incorrect memory GTX 770 linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia, graphics

Have a new secondhand PC, running Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64 Bit, Linux Kernel: 3.13.0-37-generic. System info recognises two VGA cards - onboard and the GTX 770.

However, when I query

```
lscpi -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
```

The response I get is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] [10de:1184] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8465]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
Memory at da000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at db000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

However this graphics card is supposed to have 2GB GDDR5 as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are running your card with nouveau(open source drivers) or nvidia drivers? I guess you are running on open source!

You should try to install the proprietary drivers (nvidia drivers) to see if it is really reading your card wrong. With nvidia-setting you should be able to see everything related to your GPU.

This site should show you how to install them easily  [mintguide.org](http://mintguide.org/system/304-install-the-nvidia-driver-346-35-for-linux-mint.html).

[image]
<sub>(source: [tomshardware.com](http://img.tomshardware.com/us/2006/06/01/a_continuing_work_in_progress/sol-figure07-nvidia-xserver-settings.jpg))</sub>

image source : tomshardware.com

This is an old image but you should see the right information!

Keep me posted !

Comment: Hey :)

Thanks for response.

nvidia settings is reading the correct memory

I have been working converting extremely large bitmaps to vectors so I believe that I'm just experiencing the limit of my hardware, guess i'll just wait till i can upgrade :)